# MVC4 OAuth HasLocalAccount method throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I have a MVC4 Application that spends debug process locally without enabling Register External site clients (like twitter , etc...) yet. And I'm Using custom membership user and role providers. But unfortunately when I browse the 'Manage' Page get this error:

> **Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.**

And the stack trace :

> [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
>      Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyProvider() +91
>      Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(Int32 userId) +41
>      Melk.Controllers.AccountController.Manage(Nullable`1 message) in C:\Users\AmirMehr\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Melk\Melk\Controllers\AccountController.cs:141
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +153
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +211
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult *) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +223
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass2a.b_*20() +24
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass25.b_*22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Please help to be aware. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VerifyProvider` will throw if you are using the `SimpleMembershipProvider` and it is not yet initialized, or if the provider does not inherit from `ExtendedMembershipProvider`.

If you are using WebSecurity out of the box, you need to make sure `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` is called first.

If you are using custom providers, make sure they are inheriting from `ExtendedMembershipProvider` (or `SimpleMembershipProvider`), otherwise you cannot use this function.

Comment: My role provider inherited from RoleProvider and membership from MembershipProvider. Is it wrong? DB is Initialized too.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use WebSecurity, you need to inherit from `ExtendedMembershipProvider`.

Comment: may you describe and brighten me in this post too? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562758/differences-among-types-of-memberships-in-mvc?noredirect=1#comment27312569_18562758