# General rules for when to use which types of memberships in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

Already I have known 3 types of memberships in Microsoft MVC. They are:

1. [membershipprovider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx)
2. [extendedmembershipprovider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.extendedmembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)
3. [simplemembershipprovider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

Obviously they have differences to use.
**What is the key advantage for selecting each of them?** 
May somebody describe?

Thanks.

Comment: Those are some fairly open-ended questions. Perhaps you could be more specific?

Comment: I saw projects that use one of this classes to provide membership system. my meaning is : what differences exists among them to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) from Jon Galloway goes into great detail explaining what I think it is you are asking.

The article includes a class diagram that shows the relationship between all three classes that you have listed.

The relevant take-away quote is this one:

> SimpleMembershipProvider is an implementaiton of an
>   ExtendedMembershipProvider, which inherits from MembershipProvider and
>   adds some other account / OAuth related things.

Be sure to look at the class diagram, it is in the section called *How SimpleMembership integrates with ASP.NET Membership*

Hope that helps.

Comment: so each person may implement one of the above memberships. I want to know what is key feature to select one of them?

Answer (score 0):

MembershipProvider is an abstract class that all other membership providers inherit from.   You can't create an instance of it, because it's abstract.

There are other membership providers, such as SqlMembershipProvider, and the universal membership providers, that inherit from this as well, not to mention MySqlMembershipProvider, OracleMembershipProvider, etc.. etc.. etc..

Microsoft created a more simplified provider model, called the ExtendedMembershipProvider, which also inherits from MembershipProvider.  Like MembershipProvider, ExtendedMembershipProvider is also abstract and cannot be instantiated.  You need to inherit from it.

SimpleMembershipProvider inherits from ExendedMembershipProvider, and there may be others as well.

Comment: but I have implemented custom membership provider from membershipprovider class before. They are extendable/usable for web application user managements. look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429897/mvc4-oauth-haslocalaccount-method-throws-invalidoperationexception

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi - I don't know what you're asking here.  Of course you can implement a custom provider, what are you trying to say?

Comment: I say they are usable classes to provide membership perhaps in abstract way. My question refers to potentiality of each class. So we can use them in better way, and get more greater results from using them. In other words I want to know Microsoft purpose to create each of them?

Comment: If you have already Reflectored or ILSpied the classes in question and noticed the difference in functionality they offer/add, you might have some specific question.